# cannot find -lsocket, compiling problem in client-server program?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ubuntu

I am trying to do some socket programming, writing a simple client-server program. But when I try to compile the program, I get this error.

```
gcc -o showip showip.c -lnsl -lsocket -lresolv
showip.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/usr/bin/ld.real: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I try to install lib doing this,

```
sudo apt-get install happycoders-libsocket-dev
```

and when I compile, I still get the same error.

How can I get rid of this ?
Thanks.

Comment: On Linux the socket functions are in libc so no special link options are needed.  On Solaris you need -lsocket.

Comment: I was on Ubuntu, and had the same issue. Reading mark4o's comment, I just got rid of the -lsocket flag and that allowed the program I was trying to compile to successfully compile and run. Thanks mark4o!

Comment: @mark4o that should be the real answer. Removing this from the makefile fixed my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Normally the library binary comes with one package and the headers with another one with tha same name and a "-dev" behind.

Maybe you are missing plain happycoders-libsocket.

You are missing this package [happycoders-libsocket](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/happycoders-libsocket), assuming you are in ubuntu.

Apparently happycoders-libsocket package in ubuntu is placing the libsocket.so libreary in /usr/lib/happycoders/ and that is not a standard place for libs, it should be directly inside /usr/lib/. Using -L you instruct the compiler, or linker in this case, to search for library files in that extra directory

Comment: I try to install it doing sudo apt-get install happycoders-libsocket, and it says it is already installed

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but I would really appreciate if you could explain why -lsocket wasn't working and pointers to any place where I can get more information about this. Thanks, again.

Comment: @seg.server.fault.  -lsocket tells your linker to link against the library libsocket.so.  The -L option tells the linker WHERE to look for libraries